# Trying to declare arrays over an array of texts

Tags: python, arrays, concatenation

```
serie = ["HeatEOP", "CoolantFGPM", "CoolingWF", "OilTA"]

for x in serie:
  "v"+x = []
  "ts"+x = []
```

What I would expect to do was create 8 arrays. vHeatEOP, tsHeatEOP, vCoolantFGPM, tsCoolantFGPM, vCoolingWF, tsCoolingWF, vOilTA, tsOilTA.

Comment: Your left hand side has an operator ("+") ..you are trying to assign something on the right side to an operator .. I doubt the code runs in the first place

Comment: How would that even work (LHS should logically be an identifier to store the variable not a value (string in your case))? You would be better off using dictionaries.

Comment: What is it that you want to achieve? .. the title has very little information